# React history.push() is updating url but not navigating to it in browser?

Tags: reactjs

When I tried to run my react code I faced this problem. When I click on the Login button it updates the url to http://localhost:3000/dashboard. But does not navigate.

This is my code index.js

```
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
ReactDOM.render(<BrowserRouter><App /></BrowserRouter>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

App.js

```
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {

 let history = useHistory();

 const handleclick = () => {

     history.push("/dashboard");

}

return (
<>
   <div className="container">
    
    <FormControl id="submit">
      
      <Button type="button" className="btn btn-danger mt-2" onClick={ handleclick }> Login </Button>
      
    </FormControl>
    
  </div>
  </>
 );
}
export default App;
```

Dashboard.js

```
function Dashboard () {
return (
  <>
    <h1>hi</h1>
  </>
)
}


export default Dashboard;
```

Comment: Where have you definned your Dashboard route?

Comment: You need to use react router switch and define dashboard route  in ```app.js``` .. Working example https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-basic-forked-ojsuy

Comment: @maniraj Can you give a little bit of explanation. Why did your code work even if BasicExample was not imported in any component?

Comment: @BoidurjaTalukdar, Its already been imported inside ```index.js``` file (https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-basic-forked-qhdij?file=/index.js) in the name of ```App``` .. When we use export default, we can use any name to import it. Reference: https://medium.com/@etherealm/named-export-vs-default-export-in-es6-affb483a0910